# dpkg: error processing archive minergate-cli.deb

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg

I am a newbie in using Ubuntu OS. I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 (VPS). I am not sure about if it is 64bit or 32bit. 
I am trying to install "MinerGate" (Software for minning cryptocurrencies). When I enter the command

```
sudo apt-get update && wget https://minergate.com/download/deb-cli -O minergate-cli.deb && sudo dpkg -i minergate-cli.deb
```

It downloads the file and when It tries to install it, I get this error

```
dpkg: error processing archive minergate-cli.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (ppc64el)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 minergate-cli.deb
```

Comment: Your system is `ppc64el`, aka IBM POWER 64-bit/PowerPC. It is not an Intel/AMD 64-bit/32-bit system.

Comment: So I can,t install minergate on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method to install MinerGate 1.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 and later

## Update the system dependencies

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

## First try to install MinerGate 1.5 hoping it will work

```
sudo wget https://minergate.com/download/xfast-ubuntu-cli -O MinerGate-xFast-cli-1.5-ubuntu && sudo dpkg -i MinerGate-xFast-cli-1.5-ubuntu
```

## Try to install missing dependency by manually

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev
```

## Fail to do so, then try to fix it

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

## Retry to install MinerGate 1.5

```
sudo wget https://minergate.com/download/xfast-ubuntu-cli -O MinerGate-xFast-cli-1.5-ubuntu && sudo dpkg -i MinerGate-xFast-cli-1.5-ubuntu
```

you will be a success with flying colors...

Comment: Thanks ! that helped

Answer (score 0):

Is Minergate provide deb package for your architecture? If not, you could download the source code and build it yourself

Comment: I don,t think they provide deb package..

Comment: So you have to build Minergate for your system from source code, right?

Comment: How can I do that? I have no idea about that. I just started using ubuntu a few days ago.

Comment: Just follow any instruction on README or INSTALL after extracting the source code carefully.